# Spring Tool Suite doesn't have expected project options

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide#CreateSpringMVCProject, but STS does not have the same options.

Here's the options they say I should have:
[image]

And Here's the options I actually have:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I would like to recommend to use Spring Boot as a starting point. The Web MVC example project from the "Spring Legacy Project" wizard is quite a bit outdated, uses XML to config the Spring app, uses an outdated Spring version, etc. Spring Boot is the way to go forward, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tutorial is based on Spring Tool Suite IDE 3.2.0, whereas the most recent version is 3.7.something. The option has been renamed to "**Spring Legacy Project**".